# How to make this CSS3 styled loading animation on iOS?

Tags: ios, css, animation, uiview, cgrect

I have made a pure CSS3 styled loading animation with this code:

http:// codepen.io/anon/pen/zFvfh

But I want to make this animation implemented on iOS without using image, and be reusable.

How to do that?

Comment: The pen even doesn't exist.

Comment: @Benjamin It's OK for me to open for that. Just remove the blank before `codepen.io` on the url